# Swapping between code using comments

Tags: c, comments

I've come up with a quick way to swap between two variations on code using comments for quick testing:

```
doSomeNormalCode();
findAnObject()
//*/
.doA()
/*/
.doB()
//*/
;
additionalNormalCode();
```

this calls `findAnObject().doA();`  Simply removing the first `/` swaps between `.doA()` and `.doB()`.  This can be extended by adding more `/*/` lines:

```
doSomeNormalCode();
findAnObject()
//*/
.doA()
/*/
.doB()
/*/
.doC()
/*/
.doD()
/*/
.doE()
//*/
;
additionalNormalCode();
```

This executes `findAnObject().doA().doC().doE();`  You can turn any `/*/` into a `//*/` to toggle all of the lines below it.  So adding a `/` before `.doB()` would change it to `findAnObject().doA().doB().doD().doF();`

This of course is all very complicated.  I've gotten used to it and it works very quickly for me.  I *never* keep it in committed code, just for swapping between options for testing very quickly.

Is there an easier way to *quickly* swap between various options, other than commenting out one section and uncommenting another section, which can be cumbersome if there are /**/ comments within the commented out code, requiring every line to be prefaced with `//`.

I'm obviously referring to C-style comments here, but I'd also be interested in other languages as well.

Answer (score 6):

how about

```
#if 0
  doA()
#else
  doB()
#endif
```

just switch the 0 for a 1 for starters. Or use defines, once you have more than 2 options.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` and `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, `#else` work well for this.

For eg.

```
#ifdef DEFA
doA();
#endif

#ifdef DEFB
doB();
#endif
```

In most compilers, you can pass the #define in the command line to switch between options.

For eg, in Visual C++, you can compile as

`cl /DDEFA a.c`

or

`cl /DDEFB a.c`

or

`cl /DDEFA /DDEFB a.c`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the first answer

```
#define DOB

#ifdef DOA
doA()
#elif DOB
doB()
#elif DOC
doC()
#endif
```